# React Native Error: spawn gradlew.bat ENOENT

Tags: react-native

I did all the prerequisites for using `react native` on Windows and created the project by executing the `npx react-native init myplatform` command but I encountered the following error after the `npx react-native run-android` command and couldn't believe my eyes because some time ago it was running on the system without any problems.

[image]

react native version : 0.63.4

Comment: This is the common error that occurs sometimes,
we can try to run the app from the android studio

Comment: Thank you! You know it worked but it doesn't work all the time, I don't know why. I started my new project using expo now

Comment: True, that by just opening the app from the Android Studio IDE, and not even doing a build, but simply opening the project, and letting it do some syncing, indeed made the issue went away.

Answer (score 2):

This error is because of your gradlew.bat file is corrupt try add new one then try again.

you can find new file from react native github

[gradlew.bat](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/gradlew.bat)

try this!

Answer (score 0):

In my case i'm solved with:

```
tns install
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but your command is for native script while I use react native

Comment: @AliRezaie sorry my bad, please make sure your device is connected with command  "adb devices" &  run this, "cd android && gradlew clean && gradlew cleanBuildCache && cd.."

Comment: When I ran gradlew clean in this project, I got a not recognized error. Then I created a new project with version 0.63.3 and the project ran without any problems

Comment: I'm having the same problem. How did you change the version?

Comment: @Walmac , In Windows with the command npx react-native init ProjectName --version X.XX.X

Answer (score 0):

1. miss gradlew shell script
2. miss debug.keystore (optional)
3. match downloaded SDK version, if NDK needed, do the same process

example build.gradle

```
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
        kotlin_version = "1.3.50"
        kotlinVersion = "$kotlin_version"
        androidXCore = "1.6.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

delete gradlew.bat & gradlew file from this path  `project/android/` and copy that files from another react native project & paste this into thi path `project/android/` then run `npm install` & run the project